# difference between two times

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, localtime

I am trying to get the difference between two times for performance testing of some code. First, i get the local time of the environment, Run the code to be perf tested and then get local time again. After that i subtract the time to see how long the test took. I am trying to be accurate up to minutes,seconds and microseconds.
I find interesting that this works if i set a print after each time i get the time:

```
startTest= datetime.datetime.now()
print startTest
```

i get:

```
TotalTime:  0:00:00.328000
```

However, it fails if i dont add any print statements after i get the local time, this is what im doing:

```
import datetime

startTest= datetime.datetime.now()
```

> ```
>       #Code to be Tested#
> ```

```
endTest= datetime.datetime.now()
testTime = endTest - startTest
print 'TotalTime:  ',testTime
```

This gives me the following output:

```
TotalTime:  0:00:00
```

any idea how to get it to print out on the format`0:00:00.000000`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, what is the exact version of Python?

Comment: look into python cProfile module ... and or the timeit module ....

Comment: i agree, is pretty odd! i am running 2.7.1

Comment: I can see the sub-second part on 2.6.6.

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer your question, but you could have a look at Pythons `timeit` module
http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html
which is for performance testing of small code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

It prints the microseconds only if there is there is a nonzero value in the `microseconds` attribute of the the `datetime.timedelta` object.

If you want a different behavior, write your own string formatting function. Something like:

```
def delta_to_string(tdelta):
    return '%s days, %02d:%02d:%09.6f' % (
        tdelta.days,
        tdelta.seconds / 3600,
        (tdelta.seconds / 60) % 60,
        (tdelta.seconds % 60) + (tdelta.microseconds / 10**6.))
```

The `%09.6f` format means 9 digits total for a float including decimal, add leading 0s if necessary, 6 digits max for decimal portion. If you want more or fewer digits, you have to change both the total number of digits and the decimal part - 10 decimal places would be `%013.10f`.

This prints every part of the `timedelta` object. Let's try it:

```
>>> delta_to_string((datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now()))
'0 days, 00:00:00.000000'
```

I think you wanted to preserve the functionality of not printing days if days is 0...

```
def delta_to_string(tdelta):
    return '%s%02d:%02d:%09.6f' % (
        ('%s days, ' % tdelta.days) if tdelta.days else '',
        tdelta.seconds / 3600,
        (tdelta.seconds / 60) % 60,
        (tdelta.seconds % 60) + (tdelta.microseconds / 10**6.))
```

Now the results are:

```
>>> s1 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> s2 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> delta_to_string(s1 - s2)
'-1 days, 23:59:57.387000'
>>> print (s1 - s2)
-1 day, 23:59:57.387000
>>> delta_to_string(s2 - s1)
'00:00:02.613000'
>>> print (s2 - s1)
0:00:02.613000
>>> delta_to_string(s2 - s2)
'00:00:00.000000'
>>> print (s2 - s2)
0:00:00
```

Doesn't behave quite the same way as the built in **str** function... I'll leave the differences as an "exercise for the reader."